# Reset EOF for reading a .dat file?

Tags: c

sorry if this is something obvious, i currently have to learn quickly C.

I have a readList function that reads from a .dat file, works fine. I start it by creating an integer and check if equal to EOF

```
void readLine1(){

int i;

while(i != EOF){
 //take the data and add it to a list.
}
```

now, i want to read from another .dat file in the same .c file where the first readLine is located:

```
void readLine2(){

int x;

while(x != EOF){
 //take the data and add it to a second list.
}
```

however, this isn't working, as it seems that X == EOF. Why is that so? And is there a way to reset the EOF without any issues after the first readLine1()?

I could separate it and move it to another .h /.c file, but that seems to me a little bit unnecessary?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `int x` has not been initilaised (as compiler should warn) and so it's possible it is already `-1`.

Comment: Please initialise your automatic variables within functions. If you don't do this, they assume a junk value from the stack, and behaviour is undefined if you depend on them for making decisions. So init them to zero. In contrast, global variables (declared on the file scope) *will* be zero initialized

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I will try it out and report back in a moment

Comment: Got it somehow working. I get a pointer allocated error, but it seems to be something different. If not, i will reply here if thats okay. Have a great evening!

Comment: Sure. If you have memory problems, then perhaps include some example code too. We can't really tell what the issue is otherwise.

Comment: @Micrified thanks! Was able to fix it, had an typo for a new object that i create for the list, i said Street *street = newStreet(street) which is wrong, should been newStreet(streetList). Thanks for helping! If you want, you can post your answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Okay! I'll post it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in functions (called local, or automatic variables) should always be initialised prior to use in C. If they're not, they assume some value based on the contents of the stack. In your case, it may have assumed `EOF` from the previous function call, given that the functions are very similar in structure.

Fixing it is just a simple change:

```
// Has value zero, since it is declared on the global scope
int y;


void readLine2(){

    // Assumes stack value, so must be initialised before use
    int x = 0;

    while(x != EOF){
        //take the data and add it to a second list.
    }
}
```